# reload page if page completed reloading in previous reloading in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

i develop an chrome extension which reload page according to user time interval input, i `setInterval` according to user input in background page and in function of setInterval i execute `location.reload()` with `chrome.tabs.executeScript`,the problem i encounter with is i want to reload if previous reload completed, i used document.readyState and check complete: `if (document.readyState == 'complete') {location.reload(true);}` in chrome.tabs.executeScript code but it dose not work properly and document.readyState is always get complete and reload occur again. i did not want use content script. what should i do? i search a lot in SO but i did not find anything.

Comment: Try without executeScript or content scripts: use chrome.tabs.get to read the tab `status` (loading/complete) and reload by using chrome.tabs.update with the same `url`. See documentation.

Comment: i have some other codes which i should execute so i need executeScript

Comment: thanks @wOxxOm, it solve my problem, i checked tab status before `chrome.tabs.executeScript` call.